# Cloudpage performance by calling multiple content blocks using contentblockID AmpScript function in html blocks

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

We are developing a cloudpage using multiple html blocks ( Using new content builderfunctionality) ,  so is there any performance issues if we create code snippets in content builder and called those html/Code snippets via contentblockbyid ampscript function in CloudPage in each html block?

Or is it recommended to use html,ampscript code directly in CloudPage in html block ? Without calling code snippets using contentblockbyid ampscript function?

Comment: you cannot get a definite answer; you are asking for gut feeling - mine is, you should be fine. I rely heavily on contentblockById, also in cloudpages. after all, contentBlockById is safe to be used in emails at send time, meaning for millions of records within seconds.

Comment: @jonasLamberty - there is a definite answer because the content block versus custom coding is irrelevant to processing speed as that is all rendered and prepared on publication, same as in emails, (with data and personalization being done 'real time') meaning that when it is viewed by the end user, there is no performance difference between the two.

Comment: I was first reading the question as a  "are there going to be performance issues" topic, which obviously relies also on the stuff you do in those blocks.  (probably looked at the close flags a bit too much). As it uses the same engine, of course the answer about differences is definite. Reading it again, I think that was really the point of the question - so you're right. I just don't understand the close votes anymore :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as performance, there is no difference as, similar to Triggered Send / Journey emails, once you publish it, it creates a 'snapshot' of the code and uses that, not the live stuff you have in the page. This snapshot will take all of the content blocks and combine it into a single HTML page similar to the direct editing in 'Code View'.

Only differences would be around editing and re-use. Editing through multiple content blocks can be difficult to make some changes, but they also allow you to reuse these blocks in other areas without copy/paste and keep a single code source. So honestly, the only consideration should be your plan around how best to handle your content for future needs and maintenance.